# uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainIOException : Cannot load Twain Source Manager

Tags: device, scanning, twain

hi every one i was using uk.co.mmscomputing.device lib to scan images on my computer 32 bit but when i switched the project to another computer using 64bit system

i got this error =(

```
uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainIOException: Cannot load Twain Source Manager.
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.getSourceManager(jtwain.java:126)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.select(jtwain.java:154)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainScanner.select(TwainScanner.java:25)
at scan.TwainAppletExample.actionPerformed(TwainAppletExample.java:81)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:392)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:360)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

i searched all the day but with no result. thanks for ur answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible cause of the issue is that you don't have 64-bit TWAIN DSM on the machine. Try running your application as 32 bit and test again.

Comment: yes that what i did and it works now 
another solution that i have found is to download TWAINDSM.DLL for 64bit and put it in C:/windows/system32
thank u a lot anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

Download TWAINDSM.DLL for 64bit and put it in C:/windows/system32